# How to get Log table data first using two SQL Table ( SQL Server 2008 )

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a SQL select query to get log table data first using two SQL Server tables, actual why I am using log table because when user will update his file then it will stored in `Table_AttachLog` but I kind use inner join between two tables because that it log table. I know using `updateddate` column order by desc, we can get but how to use both of table.

Table_AttachLog

```
RegistrationID     uploaded File             updateddate
---------------------------------------------------------------------
101                myprofile.doc             2018-03-25 00:45:08.500
```

Table_Registration

```
RegistrationID     Name      Email                 uploaded File         submitted
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
100                Rohan     rohan@gmail.com       rohanfile.doc       2018-01-12 00:45:08.500
101                mazhar    mazhar@gmail.com      myprofile.doc       2018-03-13 00:45:08.500
102                raj       raj@gmail.com         raj.doc             2018-01-16 00:45:08.500
```

I need query that  updateddate of Table_AttachLog should come first order by desc follow below output

```
RegistrationID     Name      Email                 uploaded File         submitted
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
101                mazhar    mazhar@gmail.com      myprofile.doc       2018-03-13 00:45:08.500
100                Rohan     rohan@gmail.com       rohanfile.doc       2018-01-12 00:45:08.500
102                raj       raj@gmail.com         raj.doc             2018-01-16 00:45:08.500
```

Comment: Any answer, please ask if my question have confusion.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. You want 101 first because 101 is also in Table_AttachLog table? How to order if there are two rows in that table?

Comment: Ya 101 should come first, Table_Attachlog means he updated file thats why one record is there in that log table, other two they not update thats why they should go down in the select query without duplication. @jarlh

Comment: What if 101 has two rows in Table_AttachLog?

Comment: Distint value only should come. @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

left join isnull should do it

```
select r.*
from Table_Registration r
left join Table_AttachLog a 
  on a.RegistrationID = r.RegistrationID  
order by isnull(a.updateddate, r.submitted) desc
```

Comment: Table_Registration have 2750 data and if you run your query data should be that much only 2750. But data after executing your query data is showing 3222. @paparazzo

Comment: Please check any duplicate condition or what. @paparazzo

Comment: @user3754858  I will go with what

Comment: @user3754858 I don't care.  Answer is only as good as the question.  I am not going to put any more of my time on this.

Comment: If you sugges then i can accept your answer na. @ paparazzo

Comment: if in log table have some duplication 101 two time means that also your answer remove duplication. @paparazzo